# Using Unpublished Material for Promotion

Tags: adobe-indesign, client-relations, ethics

I've recently entered the graphic design scene and I want to promote my services on some social media platforms such as Instagram and Facebook. I know that it is okay for me to publish some of my works that I have done for previous clients. But is it okay for me to publish works that have not been approved by my client?

Answer (score 1):

Many designers showcase [proposals](https://www.behance.net/search?field=44&content=projects&sort=appreciations&time=week&featured_on_behance=true&search=proposal) and/or rejected stuff in their portfolios. Whatever clients are not buying is yours to keep, so you can just blur the logo, naming and other detail tracing back to the client, or place a fictional logo and clearly say that's a proposal.